# How can I recover deleted files in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, file-recovery

I deleted a few hundred files using `del /S`.  My backup failed, and I need to recover as many of these as possible - preferably without taking the hard drive out and using another machine.  The directory the files were in still exists.

Comment: Please do a little research first—plenty of file recovery tools exist.

Comment: When you delete from a command line the files don't go into the recycle bin, so you need file recovery software (see redbeam_'s answer).  Stop using the computer until you recover the files to reduce the risk that they will be overwritten, and do the recovery directly to another drive or thumbdrive for the same reason.  Don't try to recover to a CD/DVD because that gets written to your hard drive first.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva), or [Disk Digger](http://diskdigger.org/).

Both are available on [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/).